# SCD type 2 using SQL Server MERGE, how to capture counts?

Tags: sql-server, merge, ssis-2012

New to SQL Server and MERGE.

I am working on a MERGE statement to populate a slowly changing dimension table. My example includes both type 1 and type 2 attributes. I see examples of how to use OUTPUT to capture counts of actions, and I understand how to use OUTPUT to pass values out to an INSERT statement. What I would like to do is take the following code and somehow capture the count of UPDATE and INSERT actions for audit/logging purposes.

Very confused reading articles on OUTPUT and OUTPUT INTO, but from what I can tell, I don't think I can do what I want to do, at least not using OUTPUT.

Is there a way to capture the ACTION counts from the below statement? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thank you

```
BEGIN

 MERGE dbo.dimTable tgt
 USING dbo.stgTable src
     ON tgt.NaturalKey = src.NaturalKey
     AND tgt.IsActiveRow = 'Y'
 WHEN MATCHED
     AND EXISTS 
     (SELECT src.SCD1Field
         EXCEPT 
      SELECT tgt.SCD1Field
         )
    THEN
         UPDATE SET
             tgt.SCD1Field = src.SCD1Field ;

 INSERT dbo.dimTable (
       tgt.NaturalKey
     , tgt.SCD1Field
     , tgt.SCD2Field    
     , tgt.RowStartDate
     , tgt.RowEndDate
     , tgt.IsActiveRow
     )
SELECT
     NaturalKey
     , SCD1Field
     , SCD2Field
     , RowStartDate
     , RowEndDate
     , IsActiveRow
 FROM (
     MERGE dbo.dimTable tgt
     USING dbo.stgTable src
         ON tgt.NaturalKey = src.NaturalKey
     WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
     THEN
         INSERT (
         NaturalKey
         , SCD1Field
         , SCD2Field
         , RowStartDate
         , RowEndDate
         , IsActiveRow
         )
         VALUES (
         src.NaturalKey
         , src.SCD1Field
         , src.SCD2Field
         , GETDATE()
         , NULL
         , 'Y'
         )
     WHEN MATCHED
         AND tgt.IsActiveRow = 'Y'
         AND EXISTS 
            (
         SELECT src.SCD2Field
         EXCEPT 
         SELECT tgt.SCD2Field
             )
             THEN
                 UPDATE
                 SET IsActiveRow = 'N'
                     , RowEndDate = DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE())
     OUTPUT $ACTION Action_Out
         , src.NaturalKey
         , src.SCD1Field
         , src.SCD2Field
         , GETDATE() RowStartDate
         , NULL RowEndDate
         , 'Y' IsActiveRow
     )m
 WHERE m.Action_Out = 'UPDATE'
 END ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command itself does not provide a way to capture the ACTION counts.

What you can do, however, is to add another step of counting the ACTION results from the table you are logging them to, assuming that you have some sort of audit key or date column you can use to separate the results from the most recent execution.